# how to call the submit order name into another confirm order.where "+name" typed

Tags: java, android

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {

   EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
    String name = nameField.getText().toString();
}

public void confirmOrder  (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Order FOR: "+ name );
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare nameField as global

```
public void confirmOrder  (View view) {

        String name = nameField.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Order FOR: "+ name );
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i declare after "Order For: " 

please tell me.

Comment: Unable to understand you comment :(